# can't convert Symbol into Integer model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error that I have never seen before

can't convert Symbol into Integer

model:

```
@customers = [
    {
        :customer_name => 'James',
        :group_name => 'Latin@ Social Work Coalition',
    }
```

html.erb

```
<div id="group_name" class="group-name">
  <h1>
    <%= @customers[:group_name] %>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`@customers` is an array

```
<div id="group_name" class="group-name">
  <h1>
    <%= @customers.first[:group_name] %> #or @customers[0][:group_name]
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: when I use the first one, I get the error :undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass when I do the second one, I get the error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You cannot access the instance variables from the model in the view. You will have to set `@customers` in the controller action that renders the html.erb

Answer (score 0):

@customers is being declared as an array, which is indexed by integer, but you are passing in a symbol.

If you're looking to find a customer by :group_name

```
<%= @customers.detect { |customer| customer[:group_name] == <GROUP_WANTED> } %>
```